# Batch import fbx from all subfolders with filename script in blender

Tags: python, import

I want to check all the subfolder in the selected folder in the blender and import the fbx in it.
And I want to apply the file name of the imported model to the obj
example: file name: Model.fbx but in fbx object is cube.
By default, blender applies this name to the imported object: cube.
But I want the name of the imported object must be Model.
I think I could explain.

Import fbx from all subfolders.
Apply its own file name for each model

my try:

```
def importer(path, name):
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=path)
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        obj.name = name

def dirScan(dirs, path):
    for c in dirs:
        if os.path.isdir(path+c):
            tempd = os.listdir(path+c+'/')
            for c1 in tempd:
                if os.path.isfile(path+c+'/'+c1):
                    if os.path.splitext(c1)[1] == ".fbx":
                       importer(path+c+'/'+c1, os.path.splitext(c1)[0])
                else:
                    dirScan(os.listdir(path+c+'/'+c1))
        else:
            if os.path.splitext(c)[1] == ".fbx":
                        importer(path+c, os.path.splitext(c)[0])
```

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Comment: I wrote the code manually but it is not working as I expected https://codeshare.io/dwo9BK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively get all the files with a certain extension with [Path.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob). Get the file name with [Path.stem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem).

```
from pathlib import Path
import bpy

folder = Path(r"C:\path\to\your\folder")
fbx_files = [f for f in folder.glob("**/*.fbx") if f.is_file()]
for fbx_file in fbx_files:
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=str(fbx_file))
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        obj.name = fbx_file.stem
```

Comment: It worked great. Thank you.
I didn’t know Path.glob before